# Custom cpanel login form

Tags: javascript, php, html, cpanel

Im trying to create custom webmail login page that will pass credentials to cpanel webmail login. Question is, is it possible with some coding to just type username without domain name for my email so i can just type username without "@mywebsitename.com" 
My login form so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mail.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content-wrap">
    <form action="https://mywebsite.com:2096/login/" method="post">
      <input name="login_theme" type="hidden" value="cpanel" />
      <div class="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form method="post">
          <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
          <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Let me in.</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--

        var init = function() {
          document.getElementById("user").value = '';
          document.getElementById("pass").value = '';
          document.getElementById("user").focus();
        };

        if (window.addEventListener) {
          window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
        } else if (document.addEventListener) {
          document.addEventListener('load', init, false);
        }
      </script>
      <input name="goto_uri" type="hidden" value="/?login_theme=cpanel" /> </form>
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if up to date that its allowed to connect to cPanel webmail from an external form.

But for JavaScript requirements for the form itself to update the email domain, you can use this method:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="example.com/blabla" method="post"> <!-- here added ID to the form -->
    <input id="user" name="user" placeholder="Username" required="required" type="text" />
    <input id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required="required" type="password" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large" onclick="Update(); return false;" type="submit">
    Let me in.</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Update(){
   var user;
   var element = document.getElementById("user");
   user = element.value + "@example.com";
   element.value= user;
   //alert(element.value); //to debug: show new email value before submit
   document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();
   element.value=""; // debug: reset input 
}
</script>
```

Also, if it is something more complicated, you can consider upgrading to jQuery. Much smoother to work with.

Update:

If you wonder how to do this in jQuery:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
 $(".btn-primary").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var user;
   var element = $("#user");
   user = element.val() + "@example.com";
   element.val(user);
   alert(element.val()); //to debug: show new email value before submit or 
   console.log(elemetn.val());
   $("#loginForm").submit();
   element.val(""); // debug: reset input 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Worked right away when i comented out ` element.value=""; // reset input `. Thanks alot

Comment: That line is important when someone hit back and click again submit.

Comment: with it, it just keeps deleting username field whenever i click submit

Comment: it will delete it after submit, so actually, its been sent.